# XSLT Parse Repeated Element and Wrap output Under new Element

Tags: xslt

I have following lines of code in my XSLT, I am doing template match to `ExtendedAttributes` (Repeated Element) and checking for some name pattern, 
if my pattern matches then I need to grab that value and wrap with my element called `<Proxy> </Proxy>`.

```
     <xsl:for-each select="/OTF/Order/OrderHeader/ExtendedAttributes">
             <xsl:element name="Proxy">
                 <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="current()/Name = 'ProxyFNm'">
                         <xsl:element name="FirstName">
                             <xsl:value-of select="current()/Value"/>
                         </xsl:element>
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="current()/Name = 'ProxyLNm'">
                         <xsl:element name="LastName">
                             <xsl:value-of select="current()/Value"/>
                         </xsl:element>
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="current()/Name = 'ProxyContact#'">
                         <xsl:element name="Phone">
                             <xsl:value-of select="current()/Value"/>
                         </xsl:element>
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:when test="current()/Name = 'ProxyEmailID'">
                         <xsl:element name="Email">
                             <xsl:value-of select="current()/Value"/>
                         </xsl:element>
                     </xsl:when>
                 </xsl:choose>
             </xsl:element>
         </xsl:for-each>
```

**Output:**

```
  <Proxy>
     <FirstName>Rob</FirstName>
  </Proxy>
  <Proxy>
     <LastName>Johnson</LastName>
  </Proxy>
  <Proxy>
     <Email>hello@gmail.com</Email>
  </Proxy>
  <Proxy>
     <Phone>8000000000</Phone>
  </Proxy>
```

If I move `<xsl:element name="Proxy">` to about for-each I am getting my desired output and things are good.

The problem is in my input if I don't have matching `(<xsl:when test="current()/Name = 'ProxyFNm'">)` then it's creating empty element `<Proxy/>` which I don't want.

Could anyone please suggest me a better way of deal this situation?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider to show a small but representative XML input sample and the output you want to produce for that sample with XSLT. The whole code looks like you can replace it with a couple of templates and you could simply only apply those templates when your condition holds.

Comment: Thank you @MartinHonnen. I have attached sample and xslt in Dropbox here is the link. if I run with  the input EE_Proxy_OTF_Input2.xml it creates <Proxy/> element which I don;t want. Could ynou please suggest a better way. https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g5fr1x91m1qsueg/AAB6fMBZD2aZXA94wyWIz5v3a?dl=0

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g5fr1x91m1qsueg/AAB6fMBZD2aZXA94wyWIz5v3a?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `for-each` to be only applied if the conditions you have are met then you need to replace `<xsl:for-each select="/OTF/Order/OrderHeader/ExtendedAttributes">` by `<xsl:for-each select="/OTF/Order/OrderHeader/ExtendedAttributes[Name = 'ProxyFNm' or Name = 'ProxyLNm' or Name = 'ProxyContact#' or Name = 'ProxyEmailID']">`.

I would refactor the whole code into templates e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="ExtendedAttributes[Name = 'ProxyFNm']">
  <Proxy>
    <FirstName>
       <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
    </FirstName>
  </Proxy>
</xsl:template>
```

(and so on for the other possible `Name` values) and then you can replace the `for-each` with `<xsl:apply-templates select="/OTF/Order/OrderHeader/ExtendedAttributes[Name = 'ProxyFNm' or Name = 'ProxyLNm' or Name = 'ProxyContact#' or Name = 'ProxyEmailID']">`.

With XSLT 2.0 the condition `Name = 'ProxyFNm' or Name = 'ProxyLNm' or Name = 'ProxyContact#' or Name = 'ProxyEmailID'` can be expressed shorter as `Name = ('ProxyFNm', 'ProxyLNm', 'ProxyContact#', 'ProxyEmailID')`.

It might even be better to reorganize the templates as

```
<xsl:template match="ExtendedAttributes">
  <Proxy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Name"/>
  </Proxy>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ExtendedAttributes/Name[. = 'ProxyFNm']">
        <FirstName>
           <xsl:value-of select="../Value"/>
        </FirstName>
    </xsl:template>
```

of course adding similar templates for the other values of `Name`.

Comment: Thank you Martin for clean explanation. I tried to implement it but the Proxy element comes under a another template match so my new template match logic is not allowing me to create. Could you please edi the my xlst in dropbox? Please let me know if that is not possible I can paste here. Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and provide minimal but complete samples here on Stack Overflow to illustrate the problem.